# How do I add space between legend items in FLOT?

Tags: jquery, html, flot

I have the below graph and I want to add space between legend items. I have tried appending spaces to the string passed to the label with no success. Any ideas? TIA

[image: Graph]
`code`

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $.plot($("#NR"), NRLine,  {
                grid: {
                    backgroundColor: "#E5E5E5",
                    hoverable: true
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    timeformat: "%m/%d",
                    minTickSize: [7, "day"],
                    ticks: datearray


                        },
                        legend: {


                        noColumns: 4,
                        container: $("#chartLegend")} 


    }
     );
        });
```

`code`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The legend labels are in containers with the class `legendLabel`, so you just have to define CSS for what you want.  Put this in your page `<head>` tag:

```
<style>
  #chartLegend .legendLabel { padding-right:10px; }​
</style>
```

This is what it would look like:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/SZUuV/1/

Answer (score 1):

@Ryley's answer is good. If you want a little more control over each label you can put [HTML mark-up in the label itself](http://jsfiddle.net/epT3K/1/):

```
label: '<span style="padding-right:60px;">foo</span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a snippet of your code? It looks to me like [this](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=297) might be the solution that you need. Use the labelFormatter to force the setup the way that you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure how the Label Formatter would accomplish this- can you supply an example of spacing?